# Python multiprocessing - mapping private method

Tags: python, python-3.x

Generally I'm aware of pickle mechanism, but can't understand why this example:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
class Foo:
    attr = 'a class attr'
    def __test(self,x):
        print(x, self.attr)

    def test2(self):
       with Pool(4) as p:
          p.map(self.__test, [1,2,3,4])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Foo()
    f.test2()
```

complains about `__test` method?

```
return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute '__test'
```

After changing `def __test` to `def _test`(one underscore) everything works fine. Do I miss any basics knowledge of pickleing or "private" methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of a single and a double underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1301369/1544347

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer: This isn't simply a duplicate; this looks like a flaw in `pickle`, where it serializes on one end under the unmangled name, but tries to look up the mangled name on the other end.

Comment: Ah I see, retracted close vote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a flaw in [the name mangling magic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1301346/364696). The actual name of a name-mangled private function incorporates the class name, so `Foo.__test` is actually named `Foo._Foo__test`, and other methods in the class just implicitly look up that name when they use `self.__test`.

Problem is, the magic extends to preserving the `__name__` unmangled; `Foo._Foo__test.__name__` is `"__test"`. And `pickle` uses the `__name__` to serialize the method. When it tries to deserialize it on the other end, it tries to look up plain `__test`, without applying the name mangling, so it can't find `_Foo__test` (the real name).

I don't think there is any immediate solution here aside from not using a private method directly (using it indirectly via another non-private method or global function would be fine); even if you try to pass `self._Foo__test`, it'll still pickle the unmangled name from `__name__`.

The longer term solution would be to file a bug on [the Python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/); there may be a clever way to preserve the "friendly" `__name__` while still allowing `pickle` to seamlessly mangle as needed.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer with link to name mailing magic. Now it looks cleaner for me.

Comment: @Howaboutnope: I am filing a bug about this now, so don't feel obligated to do so. The underlying problem appears to be the `__reduce__` implementation of bound method objects, which serializes the method in a way that says "On unpickling, do `getattr(method.__self__, method.__func__.__name__)`" without accounting for `__name__` being unmangled.

Comment: I'd be grateful if you place link to this bug here, so others may also track it once they find this problem in a future.

Comment: @Howaboutnope: Turns out an issue for this already existed: [Issue #33007: Objects referencing private-mangled names do not roundtrip properly under pickling](https://bugs.python.org/issue33007).